# angular 4 observable stopped working

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material, observable

I was using anuglar 4 and angular material. I created an angular material table. This needs an Observable. So I was creating an Observable from an list. It worked just fine until i started deleting some components. These components had nothing to do with my table or Observable but all of the sudden it started breaking down.

Now I am getting an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this._subscribe is not a function
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I am importing Observable and the .of function in the components that use them but it won't work. I also have another project that has exactly the same imports/verions and uses the observable in the exact same way. But this project works perfectly fine.

Where i use the Observable: I subscribe to an http get response, convert a list to an Observable with `Observable.of()`.

When more information is needed please contact me.

Thanks

edit component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProjectService } from '../services/project.service';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationRef, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'bitbucket-project',
  templateUrl: './bitbucket-project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bitbucket-project.component.css'],
styles: [ `
.deadProjectTable{
  background-color: #E3F2FD;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
  float: top;
}

.projectHeader{
  color: #5C6BC0;
  font-size: 1.00em;
}

.deadProjectTitle {
  color: #3F51B5;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
`
  ]
})
export class BitbucketProjectComponent implements OnInit {
  numberOfProjects:string;
  anonymousProjects:string[] = [];
  deadProjectNameList:string[] = [];
  deadProjectKeyList:string[] = [];
  deadProjectReasonList:string[] = [];
  projectDateValue: Date
  date: number
  month: number  
  year: number
  formattedDate: string

  dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this);
  displayedColumns = ['key', 'name', 'reason'];

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService, private `dataComponent:DatasComponent) {
let project = new Project('test', 'test', 'test');
this.deadProjectsList.push(project)}`
 ngOnInit() {
this.projectNumberRequest();
this.anonymousProjectRequest();


}

projectNumberRequest() {
this.projectService.getNumberOfProjects().subscribe((numberOfProjects) => {
  console.log(numberOfProjects['value']);
  this.numberOfProjects = numberOfProjects['value'];
 this.dataComponent.returnDataList().setProjectNumber(this.numberOfProjects);
}
 );


 }
anonymousProjectRequest() {
this.projectService.getAnonymousProjects().subscribe((anonymousProjects) => {
  console.log(anonymousProjects['list']);
  this.anonymousProjects = anonymousProjects['list'];
  this.dataComponent.setAnonymousProjectsList(this.anonymousProjects);
  if (this.anonymousProjects[0] == undefined) {

  } else {

  }
});


}
formatProjectDate() {
console.log("reaches that 2")
if (this.projectDateValue != null && this.projectDateValue != undefined) {
  this.date = this.projectDateValue.getDate();
  this.month = this.projectDateValue.getMonth() + 1;
  this.year = this.projectDateValue.getFullYear();
  this.formattedDate = this.year + "-" + this.month + "-" + this.date;
  return true;
} else {
  alert("Enter valid date");
  return false;
}


}deadProjectListRequest() {
this.formatProjectDate();
this.deadProjectsList = [];
this.projectService.getDeadProjectList(this.formattedDate).subscribe((deadProjectList) => {
  console.log('reached')
  console.log(deadProjectList['list']);
  this.deadProjectNameList = deadProjectList['list'];
  this.deadProjectKeyList = deadProjectList['seondList'];
  this.deadProjectReasonList = deadProjectList['thirdList'];
  console.log(this.deadProjectNameList.length);
  for (var _i = 0; _i < this.deadProjectNameList.length; _i++) {
    let project = new Project(this.deadProjectNameList[_i], this.deadProjectKeyList[_i], this.deadProjectReasonList[_i]);
    this.deadProjectsList.push(project)
  }
  this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this);
  console.log(this.deadProjectsList[0]);
  console.log(this.deadProjectsList[1]);
});


 }
}
export class Project {

constructor(key: string, name: string, reason: string) {
      this.key = key;
      this.name = name;
      this.reason = reason;
    }
    key: string;
    name: string;
    reason: string;
  }

export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
    constructor(private projectComponent: BitbucketProjectComponent) {
      super();
      this.connect();
    }

    connect(): Observable<Project[]> {
      Observable.create(this.projectComponent.deadProjectsList)
      var tempo =  Observable.create(this.projectComponent.deadProjectsList);
      return tempo;

    }

    disconnect() {
    }
  }
```

Edit: Project Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';



@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  getNumberOfProjects() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:7990/bitbucket/rest/projects/1.0/projects/number', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=')
    });
  }

  getAnonymousProjects() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:7990/bitbucket/rest/projects/1.0/projects/anonymous', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=')
    });
  }

  getDeadProjects(datum: String) {
    console.log(datum);
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:7990/bitbucket/rest/projects/1.0/projects/dead/' + datum, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=')
    });
  }

  getDeadProjectList(datum: String){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:7990/bitbucket/rest/projects/1.0/projects/dead/list/' + datum, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=')
    });
  }



}
```

Comment: Can you please show the Observable and the subscriber methods? It would be better if you could paste the entire component code.

Comment: I have added the full component. If you need anything else please let me know.

Comment: Post your `project` service

Comment: I have added the project service

Comment: This error occurs, when you try to subscribe to something that is not Observable. Your service looks fine. Did you try to comment code where you subscribe to find on what method error occurs?

Comment: Can you also tell me that exactly on which subscriber are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this in your serive method :

add `map()` inside the services all methods

```
getNumberOfProjects() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:7990/bitbucket/rest/projects/1.0/projects/number', {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=')
    }).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: It cant find the method .map. it gives me this error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'
And i think it isn't the problem, because another component uses this service too, but it works perfectly. And one day ago this worked too.

Comment: the solution is `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'; `